# Nested under nested form in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I need to help in building relationship for this scenario:

I have 3 models: `Campaign`, `CampaignPost`, `User`

I want to achieve something like the ff:

1. Campaign has many campaign_posts
2. User has many CampaignPost per campaign
3. CampaignPost belongs to User
4. CampaignPost belongs to Campaign

Mockup: http://d.pr/i/uXq6

In creating a fresh new campaign, current_user can add CampaignPost into a campaign and eventually CampaignPost will be grouped by User. And will calculate # of posts per User in one Campaign

First what I did is I nest CampaignPost in User model:

user.rb:

```
# Campaign Posts
  has_many :campaign_posts
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :campaign_posts, :allow_destroy => true, 
                                :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:post].blank? }
```

campaign_post.rb

```
class CampaignPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :campaign_id, :post, :user_id

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :campaign
end
```

campaign.rb

```
  # Users
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users

  has_many :campaign_posts
```

My edit form:

```
= simple_form_for(@campaign, remote: true) do |f|
  .admin_tracker_wrapper
    .new_campaign_header_bg
      .new_campaign_header
        = image_tag('/assets/admin_wrench_03.png')
        %b= "Admin"
    .new_campaign_bg#new_campaign_bg1
      .inputs#inputs_new
        = f.input :name, label: false, placeholder: "Enter campaign name.."
        = f.text_area :objective, placeholder: "Enter objective.."

        = submit_tag "Edit", class:"edit_campaign_btn"

    - @campaign.campaign_posts.build
    .new_campaign_bg#new_campaign_bg2
      - @campaign.users.each do |user|
        .post_header
          .row-fluid
            .span1
              .circle
                - if user.photo_url.blank?
                  = image_tag 'avatar.png'
                - else
                  = image_tag user.photo_url, :alt=>''
            .span2.post_header_full_name
              %span.full_name= user.full_name
              %br
              - if @campaign.campaign_posts.count <= 1
                %span.posts_count= "#{@campaign.campaign_posts.count} Post"
              - else
                %span.posts_count= "#{@campaign.campaign_posts.count} Posts"
            .span1.pull-right
              %a{href: "#", class:"title"} &nbsp;
        %hr
        %br
        #d-form
          - @campaign.campaign_posts.each.with_index(1) do |campaign,index|
            /= campaign.post
            .inputs#inputs_edit
              = user.fields_for :campaign_posts, campaign do |c|
                %span.post_index= "#{index} . "
                &nbsp;
                = c.text_field :post
                = submit_tag "Enter", class:"enter_campaign_btn"
                %hr
```

In my form, I have @campaign as the parent form and then I nest users via `@campaign.users`,
then have the `fields_for` ready for `campaign_posts`

But `fields_for` `campaign_posts` aren't showing and I think there's something wrong about the relationship or the form itself.

Any workarounds will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you will need to review how `fields_for` work. There are some pretty nice tutorials on the railscasts website: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised

The code `user.fields_for` should raise an error as far as I know. `fields_for` is a method on FormBuilder and should not be present on the User model.

So when you are editing in the context of a `@campaign` (that's what you start with in your form). You need to make sure that all the stuff is mapped to that campaign as well. IE you will need to have the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` on the campaign, not on the user etc.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem is with this line:

```
- @campaign.campaign_posts.build
```

A call to build will instantiate one (or more) instances of the class (CampaignPost) and return them to you but *not* add them to the campaign_posts collection.  The view assumes that they are added to the collection.

I'd consider using the controller to retrieve the collection of campaign_posts as an instance variable and then using that in the view.

```
@campaign_posts = @campaign.campaign_posts.count.zero? ? [@campaign.campaign_posts.build] : @campaign.campaign_posts
```

Also, is the @campaign.campaign_posts.each.with_index(1) a typo (@campaign.campaign_posts.each_with_index)?